# invalid configuration argument on thrust::sort_by_key

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have a problem when trying to use sort_by_key:

I get the following error in the terminal:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
>     what():  after cub_::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs(1): invalid configuration argument

The CUDA Code: (real = float/double)

```
//Declare and populate device vectors
//---------------------------------------------
thrust::device_vector<real> d_cellXPositions(h_cellXPositions);
real * d_cellXPositions_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_cellXPositions[0]);

thrust::device_vector<real> d_cellYPositions(h_cellYPositions);
real * d_cellYPositions_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_cellYPositions[0]);

thrust::device_vector<uint> d_results(_w * _h);
uint * d_results_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_results[0]);
//---------------------------------------------

//Declare hash and cell occ containers
//---------------------------------------------
thrust::device_vector<uint> d_cellOcc(GRID_RES*GRID_RES, 0);
uint * d_cellOcc_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_cellOcc[0]);

thrust::device_vector<uint> d_hash(_cellCount, 0);
uint * d_hash_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_hash[0]);
//---------------------------------------------


//Launch kernels
//---------------------------------------------
uint blockCount = std::ceil(_w*_h)/1024;
uint threadCount = (_w*_h)/blockCount + 1;

printf("Cell count = %d; Hash Size = %d; xPosCount = %d; yPosCount = %d\n",_cellCount, d_hash.size(), d_cellXPositions.size(), d_cellYPositions.size());

std::cout << "Starting kernels \n";

g_pointHash<<<blockCount, threadCount>>>(d_hash_ptr, d_cellXPositions_ptr, d_cellYPositions_ptr, GRID_RES, _w, _h);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
checkCUDAErr();

g_countCellOcc<<<blockCount, threadCount>>>(d_hash_ptr, d_cellOcc_ptr, _w*_h);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
thrust::copy(d_hash.begin(), d_hash.end(), std::ostream_iterator<uint>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << "~ \n";

//Exclusive scan the cell occ to get the starting indicies

auto tuple = thrust::make_tuple(d_cellXPositions.begin(), d_cellYPositions.begin());
auto zipit = thrust::make_zip_iterator(tuple);
thrust::sort_by_key(d_hash.begin(), d_hash.end(), zipit);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
```

Output of CUDA-memcheck:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
CUDA INFO -------------------
Runtime Version: 7050
Driver Version: 8000
GPU INFO---------------------
Device name: GeForce GTX 1080
Memory Clock Rate (KHz): 5005000
Memory Bus Width (bits): 256
Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): 320.320000
-----------------------------
Left Button Pressed
Cell count = 20; Hash Size = 20; xPosCount = 20; yPosCount = 20
Starting kernels 
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration (error 9) due to "invalid configuration argument" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef343]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5 (cudaLaunch + 0x17e) [0x2ed1e]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 [0xace82]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_Z40__device_stub__Z11g_pointHashPjPKdS1_jjjPjPKdS1_jjj + 0x10b) [0xac5b6]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_Z11g_pointHashPjPKdS1_jjj + 0x43) [0xac5fb]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN10CUDASolver14makeDiagram_NNEjjj + 0x48f) [0x83b9b]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x94c2]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv + 0x659) [0x29bf89]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton7clickedEb + 0x32) [0x306c92]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x306e94]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x308a2e]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton17mouseReleaseEventEP11QMouseEvent + 0xcc) [0x308b7c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent + 0x1f8) [0x191a48]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0xc03) [0x15b2c3]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate14sendMouseEventEP7QWidgetP11QMouseEventS1_S1_PS1_R8QPointerIS0_Eb + 0x1df) [0x159f2f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1aaec6]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1ad81b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x227) [0x15a8e7]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate17processMouseEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate10MouseEventE + 0x370) [0x12cf90]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate24processWindowSystemEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate17WindowSystemEventE + 0x105) [0x12ed85]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QWindowSystemInterface22sendWindowSystemEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xbb) [0x10ad7b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 [0xb0fa0]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_dispatch + 0x15a) [0x49d7a]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0x4a0b8]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_iteration + 0x2c) [0x4a16c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0x5f) [0x2c393f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xea) [0x2705ea]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 0x84) [0x278a44]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x734d]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21b35]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x75a7]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration (error 9) due to "invalid configuration argument" on CUDA API call to cudaGetLastError. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef343]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5 (cudaGetLastError + 0x163) [0x30713]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN10CUDASolver12checkCUDAErrEv + 0x11) [0x83591]
Error: invalid configuration argument
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN10CUDASolver14makeDiagram_NNEjjj + 0x49e) [0x83baa]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x94c2]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv + 0x659) [0x29bf89]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton7clickedEb + 0x32) [0x306c92]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x306e94]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x308a2e]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton17mouseReleaseEventEP11QMouseEvent + 0xcc) [0x308b7c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent + 0x1f8) [0x191a48]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0xc03) [0x15b2c3]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate14sendMouseEventEP7QWidgetP11QMouseEventS1_S1_PS1_R8QPointerIS0_Eb + 0x1df) [0x159f2f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1aaec6]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1ad81b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x227) [0x15a8e7]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate17processMouseEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate10MouseEventE + 0x370) [0x12cf90]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate24processWindowSystemEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate17WindowSystemEventE + 0x105) [0x12ed85]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QWindowSystemInterface22sendWindowSystemEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xbb) [0x10ad7b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 [0xb0fa0]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_dispatch + 0x15a) [0x49d7a]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0x4a0b8]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_iteration + 0x2c) [0x4a16c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0x5f) [0x2c393f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xea) [0x2705ea]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 0x84) [0x278a44]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x734d]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21b35]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x75a7]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration (error 9) due to "invalid configuration argument" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunch. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef343]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5 (cudaLaunch + 0x17e) [0x2ed1e]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 [0xace82]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_Z37__device_stub__Z14g_countCellOccPjS_jPjS_j + 0x93) [0xac690]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_Z14g_countCellOccPjS_j + 0x29) [0xac6bb]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN10CUDASolver14makeDiagram_NNEjjj + 0x531) [0x83c3d]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x94c2]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv + 0x659) [0x29bf89]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton7clickedEb + 0x32) [0x306c92]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x306e94]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x308a2e]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton17mouseReleaseEventEP11QMouseEvent + 0xcc) [0x308b7c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent + 0x1f8) [0x191a48]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0xc03) [0x15b2c3]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate14sendMouseEventEP7QWidgetP11QMouseEventS1_S1_PS1_R8QPointerIS0_Eb + 0x1df) [0x159f2f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1aaec6]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1ad81b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x227) [0x15a8e7]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate17processMouseEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate10MouseEventE + 0x370) [0x12cf90]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate24processWindowSystemEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate17WindowSystemEventE + 0x105) [0x12ed85]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QWindowSystemInterface22sendWindowSystemEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xbb) [0x10ad7b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 [0xb0fa0]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_dispatch + 0x15a) [0x49d7a]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0x4a0b8]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_iteration + 0x2c) [0x4a16c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0x5f) [0x2c393f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xea) [0x2705ea]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 0x84) [0x278a44]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x734d]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21b35]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x75a7]
=========
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ~ 
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidConfiguration (error 9) due to "invalid configuration argument" on CUDA API call to cudaPeekAtLastError. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1 [0x2ef343]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5 (cudaPeekAtLastError + 0x163) [0x305a3]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail4cub_15DeviceRadixSort9SortPairsIjNS_5tupleIddNS_9null_typeES7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_EEEE9cudaErrorPvRmRNS3_12DoubleBufferIT_EERNSC_IT0_EEiiiP11CUstream_stb + 0x8312) [0x9d4e5]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail24stable_radix_sort_detail22cub_sort_pairs_wrapperIjNS_5tupleIddNS_9null_typeES7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_EEEE9cudaErrorPvRmRNS2_4cub_12DoubleBufferIT_EERNSD_IT0_EEiNS_4lessISE_EEiiP11CUstream_stbEN10workaround9host_pathESA_SB_RNSD_IjEERNSD_IS8_EEiNSK_IjEEiiSN_b + 0x5d) [0x940f5]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail24stable_radix_sort_detail22cub_sort_pairs_wrapperIjNS_5tupleIddNS_9null_typeES7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_S7_EEEE9cudaErrorPvRmRNS2_4cub_12DoubleBufferIT_EERNSD_IT0_EEiNS_4lessISE_EEiiP11CUstream_stb + 0x62) [0x94159]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail24stable_radix_sort_detail26stable_radix_sort_by_key_nINS2_3tagEjNS_5tupleIddNS_9null_typeES8_S8_S8_S8_S8_S8_S8_EENS_4lessIjEEEEvRNS2_16execution_policyIT_EEPT0_mPT1_T2_ + 0x297) [0x933f6]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail24stable_radix_sort_by_keyINS2_3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS7_INS_7pointerINS_5tupleIddNS_9null_typeESD_SD_SD_SD_SD_SD_SD_EES5_NS_11use_defaultESF_EEEEEEvRNS2_16execution_policyIT_EET0_SM_T1_NS_4lessINS_14iterator_valueISM_E4typeEEE + 0xb0) [0x92743]
terminate called after throwing an instance of '=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail28stable_primitive_sort_detail28stable_primitive_sort_by_keyINS2_3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS8_INS_7pointerINS_5tupleIddNS_9null_typeESE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_EES6_NS_11use_defaultESG_EEEENS_4lessIjEEEENS4_20disable_if_bool_sortIT0_E4typeERNS2_16execution_policyIT_EESM_SM_T1_T2_ + 0x34) [0x91d3d]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail6detail28stable_primitive_sort_by_keyINS2_3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS7_INS_7pointerINS_5tupleIddNS_9null_typeESD_SD_SD_SD_SD_SD_SD_EES5_NS_11use_defaultESF_EEEEEEvRNS2_16execution_policyIT_EET0_SM_T1_NS_4lessINS_14iterator_valueISM_E4typeEEE + 0x34) [0x91260]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail18stable_sort_detail18stable_sort_by_keyINS2_3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS7_INS8_IdEEEESE_NS_9null_typeESF_SF_SF_SF_SF_SF_SF_EEEENS_4lessIjEEEENS3_24enable_if_primitive_sortIT0_T2_E4typeERNS2_16execution_policyIT_EESL_SL_T1_SM_ + 0xcb) [0x90885]
thrust::system::system_error=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail18stable_sort_by_keyINS2_3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS6_INS7_IdEEEESD_NS_9null_typeESE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_EEEENS_4lessIjEEEEvRNS2_16execution_policyIT_EET0_SN_T1_T2_EN10workaround13parallel_pathERNSJ_IS4_EES9_S9_SG_SI_ + 0x48) [0x8fe38]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system4cuda6detail18stable_sort_by_keyINS2_3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS6_INS7_IdEEEESD_NS_9null_typeESE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_EEEENS_4lessIjEEEEvRNS2_16execution_policyIT_EET0_SN_T1_T2_ + 0x48) [0x8fe82]
'
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust18stable_sort_by_keyINS_6system4cuda6detail3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS6_INS7_IdEEEESD_NS_9null_typeESE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_EEEENS_4lessIjEEEEvRKNS5_21execution_policy_baseIT_EET0_SO_T1_T2_ + 0x58) [0x8f28b]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system6detail7generic11sort_by_keyINS0_4cuda6detail3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS8_INS9_IdEEEESF_NS_9null_typeESG_SG_SG_SG_SG_SG_SG_EEEENS_4lessIjEEEEvRNS_16execution_policyIT_EET0_SP_T1_T2_ + 0x48) [0x8e3ab]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust11sort_by_keyINS_6system4cuda6detail3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS6_INS7_IdEEEESD_NS_9null_typeESE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_EEEENS_4lessIjEEEEvRKNS5_21execution_policy_baseIT_EET0_SO_T1_T2_ + 0x58) [0x8d590]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust6system6detail7generic11sort_by_keyINS0_4cuda6detail3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS8_INS9_IdEEEESF_NS_9null_typeESG_SG_SG_SG_SG_SG_SG_EEEEEEvRNS_16execution_policyIT_EET0_SN_T1_ + 0x48) [0x8c79a]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust11sort_by_keyINS_6system4cuda6detail3tagENS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS6_INS7_IdEEEESD_NS_9null_typeESE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_SE_EEEEEEvRKNS5_21execution_policy_baseIT_EET0_SM_T1_ + 0x54) [0x8b669]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN6thrust11sort_by_keyINS_6detail15normal_iteratorINS_10device_ptrIjEEEENS_12zip_iteratorINS_5tupleINS2_INS3_IdEEEES9_NS_9null_typeESA_SA_SA_SA_SA_SA_SA_EEEEEEvT_SD_T0_ + 0x46) [0x8a139]
=========     Host Frame:/home/i7469704/parallelvoronoi/Common/../lib/libsolver_gpu.so.1 (_ZN10CUDASolver14makeDiagram_NNEjjj + 0x661) [0x83d6d]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x94c2]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv + 0x659) [0x29bf89]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton7clickedEb + 0x32) [0x306c92]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x306e94]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x308a2e]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN15QAbstractButton17mouseReleaseEventEP11QMouseEvent + 0xcc) [0x308b7c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent + 0x1f8) [0x191a48]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0xc03) [0x15b2c3]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate14sendMouseEventEP7QWidgetP11QMouseEventS1_S1_PS1_R8QPointerIS0_Eb + 0x1df) [0x159f2f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1aaec6]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 [0x1ad81b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x9c) [0x1534bc]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x227) [0x15a8e7]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 0x108) [0x271e78]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate17processMouseEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate10MouseEventE + 0x370) [0x12cf90]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate24processWindowSystemEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate17WindowSystemEventE + 0x105) [0x12ed85]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (_ZN22QWindowSystemInterface22sendWindowSystemEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xbb) [0x10ad7b]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 [0xb0fa0]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_dispatch + 0x15a) [0x49d7a]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 [0x4a0b8]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (g_main_context_iteration + 0x2c) [0x4a16c]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN20QEventDispatcherGlib13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0x5f) [0x2c393f]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 0xea) [0x2705ea]
=========     Host Frame:/opt/Qt5.9.0/5.9/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (_ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 0x84) [0x278a44]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x734d]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21b35]
=========     Host Frame:application [0x75a7]
=========
  what():  after cub_::DeviceRadixSort::SortPairs(1): invalid configuration argument
========= Error: process didn't terminate successfully
========= Internal error (20)
========= No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found
```

Bit of an information overload but let me know if you need any more.

Comment: Are you compiling the code for the correct GPU architecture? What version of CUDA and thrust are are using?

Comment: The CUDA version appears to be 7.5 based on the program output displayed along with `cuda-memcheck` output.  I doubt this is a thrust issue.  The calculation of `threadCount` looks suspect to me.   If `_w*_h` happens to be evenly divisible by 1024, you will get an invalid choice for threadblock size, which would result in invalid configuration argument lining up with the `cuda-memcheck` output. This question ought to have a [mcve] according to item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), note the use of the word "must".  This code is incomplete.

Comment: @talonmies I use: NVCCFLAGS = -ccbin $$HOST_COMPILER -m64 -g -G \
-arch=sm_30 \
#-gencode=arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
#-gencode=arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
#-gencode=arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
-gencode=arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 \
-gencode arch=compute_$$CUDA_COMPUTE_ARCH,code=sm_$$CUDA_COMPUTE_ARCH --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing --compiler-options -fPIC -use_fast_math --std=c++11 #--ptxas-options=-v
In my makefile

Comment: @RobertCrovella The calculation was the problem thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Questions like this are supposed to include a MCVE as indicated in item 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
2. It's doubtful to me that whatever CUDA error checking is being used is of much value, since the error here (as confirmed by OP in comments) has to do with CUDA code, not Thrust.  Whatever this line is doing:

   ```
   checkCUDAErr();
   ```

   seems to be insufficient to prevent the confusion arising here.
3. The primary issue here (as indicated by OP in the comments) seems to be that this grid/thread sizing calculation is flawed:

   ```
   uint blockCount = std::ceil(_w*_h)/1024;
   uint threadCount = (_w*_h)/blockCount + 1;
   ```

   I believe that any product of `_w*_h` that is a whole-number multiple of 1024 will produce an incorrect size for `threadCount`.  A specific example would be `_w*_h` is 1024.  Then `blockCount` will be 1.  When `blockCount` is 1, then the `threadCount` variable will end up at 1025, which is an illegal block size for CUDA.  A possible solution here might be to simply set `threadCount` to 1024, hard coded.  That is evidently the block size being used in the `blockCount` calculation, and although the kernel code is not shown, it would appear to have a correct thread-check in it, since both the current `blockCount` and `threadCount` calculations involve "rounding up".
4. Thrust has generally good error-checking, and a previous error in code unrelated to thrust may show up when you call a thrust algorithm, since it will indicate any previous errors (that have not been cleared out) as well.  However the error here (in 3 above) has nothing to do with Thrust.
5. I would encourage anyone using a Pascal GPU to upgrade to at least CUDA 8 (CUDA 7.5 seems to be used here).  I would encourage anyone using a Volta GPU to upgrade to at least CUDA 9.